# Delete from table Where date statement error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to delete some information from a table that has a date `< 16/16/2019` in C#. The query gave me an exception so I'm trying to do it directly in MS Access and even here it gave me error.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (((TableName.Date)<= #16/06/2019#));
```

If I use the above, the query gives me the result that I expect which is all information which is stored before a specific date.

But if I use the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE
FROM TableName
WHERE (((TableName.Date)<= #16/06/2019#));
```

It gives me the error:

> The search key was not found in any record

Why?

Comment: Please add your delete statement to the question.

Comment: In Access SQL month should be leading number in date: #06/16/2019#

Comment: Also, `Date` is a reserved word in Access, and should be bracketed or avoided as a field or tablename.

Comment: I tried even with month leading number in date but it gave me always the same error

Comment: Date is the translation of data from italian. The real field name is "Data"

Comment: Try this `DELETE *
FROM TableName
WHERE (((TableName.Date)<= #16/06/2019#));`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried converting your date to a number? I've dealed in the past with similar issues, working with logic conditions like `<=` or `=>` and using `CDbl` to convert a date to a number worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the information in the comments, I would suggest the following:

```
delete from TableName t where t.data <= #2019-06-16#
```

Comment: nothing, I still have the error; it doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Have you tried compacting & repairing the database?

Comment: It works! compacting & repairing resolve the problem!! Thanks!